# How to export Slack messages to Python

Tags: python, webhooks, slack

I've been trying to use outgoing webhook in Slack to export messages from the channel to my Python program but I can't find the way to do it, so I wonder if even a thing like this exists?

Comment: Refer to here: https://realpython.com/getting-started-with-the-slack-api-using-python-and-flask/ there is a section about receiving messeages from slack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slack seems to have an API you can use to retreive the messages of a given channel.
Follow this link : https://api.slack.com/messaging/retrieving

You can make a GET request to retreive the full history of the given conversation (so all the messages) :

```
GET https://slack.com/api/conversations.history?token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE&channel=CONVERSATION_ID_HERE
Content-type: application/json
```

You can easily make GET requests wiht python using the library called 'requests'.
If you're able to have a valid API token and the ID of the conversation, you will then be able to get all the messages of the chosen conversation.